# Keys casting in generators

Tags: php, arrays, generator, yield

Let me start this question with a quote on array keys from [PHP Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

> If no key is specified, the maximum of the existing integer indices is taken, and the new key will be that maximum value plus 1 (but at least 0). If no integer indices exist yet, the key will be 0 (zero).

So let's try this in the following code:

```
print_r(['4'=> 1, 2, 3]); // output: Array([4] => 1 [5] => 2 [6] => 3)
```

**Note that the first key in the array is string witch will be cast by PHP to the integer type [4]*

**Now lets try this in a generator function and yield the array keys one by one and see what happens**

```
function foo() {
    yield '4' => 1;
    yield 2;
    yield 3;
}

print_r(iterator_to_array(foo()));// output: Array([4] => 1 [0] => 2 [1] => 3)
```

I know generators do not behave like arrays but let's see what happens when the first key is actually an integer:

```
function foo() {
    yield 4 => 1; // Note 4 here is an integer
    yield 2;
    yield 3;
}

print_r(iterator_to_array(foo())); // output: Array([4] => 1 [5] => 2 [6] => 3)
```

The output is as expected.

So why this is only happens when PHP cast the keys in generators? is this a normal behavior?

Comment: My answer was bad, and I can't explain what you found, but imo this is a normal behaviour, it's because behind the Yield keyword an objet called Generator exist (which implements iterator) so basically, inside this object a treatment on keys exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in the array a key is a numerical string it will be cast by PHP to the integer type. In generators numerical string keys will not cast to integer. If you want to keep the key type, you must not use the iterator_to_array function.

```
function foo() {
    yield '4' => 1;  
    yield 2;
    yield 3;
}

foreach(foo() as $key => $value){
  var_dump($key);
}
```

Output:

```
string(1) "4"
int(0)
int(1)
```

Comment: "In generators numerical string keys will not cast to integer" do you know why?. Is this just how generators implemented in PHP or is it a bug?

Comment: I think the behavior is as shown and not a bug. To know how generators keys are implemented in PHP, the sources of PHP must study.